# Alert input name in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I got a button which, when clicked, opens a new window (alert) with input text.
Now the input text has a name, let's say `name="test"`, but I'm having problems getting that name from JS to PHP. Can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $editfile = $_POST['member'];
    $alertname = $_GET['test'];
    rename('social/'.$editfile.'.xml', 'social/'.$alertname.'.xml');
}
```

JS:

```
<input type="submit" name="edit"
    onclick="prompt('Please type new member name:', 'Member new name');"
    value="Edit" />
```

Comment: you need XHR request to pass js to php

Comment: XHR means? it new language?

Comment: Haha new language, You didn't even googled xhr... First hit! XMLHttpRequest

Comment: `window` and `alert` box are not the same. Also you say window and alert and instead use `prompt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make the prompt populate a form element that will be submitted. Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="prompt-data" name="prompt">
<input type="submit" name="edit" onclick="document.getElementById('prompt-data').value = prompt('Please type new member name:', 'Member new name');" value="Edit" />
```

Then you can get the value in your PHP using `$_POST['prompt']`.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it you have **prompt(...)** rather than alert. And you need to send that to php via POST. In this case you can have something like this in your HTML:

```
<form action="myphpscript.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="test" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Click to enter something" onClick="storeSomething()">
</form>
<script language="javascript">
    storeSomething = function () {
        var test = document.getElementById('test');
        test.value = prompt("Please enter something", "something");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is a `prompt` in his code... `onclick="prompt('...` Although he has stated `alert`